# Python: String matching on a pandas column of lists

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to do string matching on a column of lists?
E.g. I have a dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
list_items = ['apple', 'grapple', 'tackle', 'satchel', 'snapple']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':xrange(3), 'L':[np.random.choice(list_items, 3).tolist() for _ in xrange(3)]})
df

    L                           id
0   [tackle, apple, grapple]    0
1   [tackle, snapple, satchel]  1
2   [satchel, satchel, tackle]  2
```

And I want to return the rows where any item in `L` matches a string, e.g. 'grap' should return row 0, and 'sat' should return rows 1:2.

Comment: Blehh do you need lists of strings? In a DataFrame? I suppose you could do something like `df.L.apply(lambda row: any('whatever' in word for word in row))` but this whole problem feels like one you shouldn't want to have.

Comment: @miradulo what is a better way to store them in this context? Seems accessible and centralized to me but I'm fairly new to data structures.

Comment: I would mostly question why you're using a DataFrame at this point instead of just a Python `dict` mapping ids to lists or whatnot. Unless you're getting some benefit from the DataFrame it is just adding some overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use this:

```
np.random.seed(123)
list_items = ['apple', 'grapple', 'tackle', 'satchel', 'snapple']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(3), 'L':[np.random.choice(list_items, 3).tolist() for _ in range(3)]})
df
                             L  id
0    [tackle, snapple, tackle]   0
1   [grapple, satchel, tackle]   1
2  [satchel, grapple, grapple]   2
```

Use `any` and `apply`:

```
df[df.L.apply(lambda x: any('grap' in s for s in x))]
```

Output:

```
                             L  id
1   [grapple, satchel, tackle]   1
2  [satchel, grapple, grapple]   2
```

---

#### Timings:

```
%timeit df.L.apply(lambda x: any('grap' in s for s in x))
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 194 µs per loop

```
%timeit df.L.apply(lambda i: ','.join(i)).str.contains('grap')
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 481 µs per loop

```
%timeit df.L.str.join(', ').str.contains('grap')
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 529 µs per loop

Answer (score 2):

`df[df.L.apply(lambda i: ','.join(i)).str.contains('yourstring')]`

Comment: `df[df.L.str.join(', ').str.contains('grap')]` would do?